# Cannot write XML declaration. WriteStartDocument method has already written it

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web-services

I want to pass an XmlDocument as a parameter to my webservice method. After I have loaded an XML file from a path, when I try to send the XmlDocument as a parameter by webservice method, I come across this error. What can be the reason? I use StreamWriter and I close it. I don't use XmlWriter.
The development environment is VS 2008

Error Message:

> Cannot write XML declaration. WriteStartDocument method has already written it.

---

**Edit** (from comments):

I can't post all the code because it has more than 1000 lines. Also when I load Xmldocument in web, I can't use this method without problem. Maybe Webservice causes a problem?

```
Dim xml As New XmlDocument
xml.Load("\My Documents\" & xmlfile & ".xml")
myTransfer.Save_XML(xml, 1)
<<<<<<'here crashes this is my web service method
<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub Save_XML(ByVal m_xmlMyDoc As XmlDocument, ByVal p_ID As Integer)
end sub
```

Comment: Show some code, because no one of us have crystal ball

Comment: i cant send all code because it has more than 1000 lines and also when i load xmldocument in web,i cant use this method without problem.Maybe Webservice causes a problem? 
Dim xml As New XmlDocument 
xml.Load("\My Documents\" & xmlfile & ".xml") 
myTransfer.Save_XML(xml, 1) <<<<<<'here crashes 
this is my web service method <WebMethod()> _ 
Public Sub Save_XML(ByVal m_xmlMyDoc As XmlDocument, ByVal p_ID As Integer) end sub –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the [XmlDocument.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) string to the webservice instead.

You can load it back into an XmlDocument with [XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim objXmlDocument As New XmlDocument()
Dim objXmlNode As XmlNode

objXmlDocument.LoadXml("file.xml")
objXmlNode = objXmlDocument.DocumentElement

myTransfer.Save_XML(objXmlNode, 1)
```